# Read form text file and write in html

Tags: php

I have a text file on my local server. I want to read content data of this text file and write it into textbox in a html .

Could you please help me?

Comment: Google it. You'll find a lot of stuff on the subject. Key-riced, is everybody pulling those **one-liner** questions today? New trend? **Here**: https://www.google.ca/search?q=Read+form+text+file+and+write+in+html+in+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr

Comment: And your previous question didn't help? **A**: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17825897/1415724

Comment: @Fred, He was previously talking about writing a file, not reading, as best as I can tell.

Comment: @Brad Ok, yet nonetheless, the OP could've easily Google'd that. And here we have people giving away free work/scripts all day long. Yet when I asked a question months ago........ oh key-riced, did I ever get slashed. No, I learned by myself to search and persevere in doing things myself.

Comment: @Fred, How do you know he didn't Google it?  Some folks have a hard time getting started, as they don't know where to begin or what to Google for.  This is especially true when there is a language barrier.  The question is clear, and while it does not show much research effort, it is perfectly answerable.  Just because you had a difficult time a couple months ago doesn't mean you making things difficult for others is the way to go.  How else will this community improve?

Comment: @Brad Had he Google'd it, he would've at least found *something*, tried to work it and came back with his "Here's what I tried" (code). I'm all for helping someone, but I've seen too many posts here lately, where they show us no code at all and we're supposed to read their minds and give them code? I will just give them a link to PHP.net to the related subject, and/or Google with the already-setup keywords. And many have been members for months. What have they been doing all this time, watching movies? Going to the park?

Comment: @Fred, Oh, I don't disagree with the general sentiment at all.  I'm just saying that your comments didn't add anything useful to fix this situation (you could have at least provided a link to a good resource), and your comment that one of your reasons is that you didn't get good answers before doesn't help.

Comment: @Brad It had nothing to do with my own personal experience. You'll notice the last time I asked a question on SO, is months ago. I totally agree with you in improving this community, 100%. I just feel that, the OP should have at the least, tell us what he tried and/or where he/she was having difficulty with, that's all. It falls under the "how to ask a question" category. ;-)

Comment: @Fred, Yes, I agree with you there.

Comment: @Brad I'm glad we were able to talk about this in a civil manner. I will do as you mentioned earlier and provide a useful link to others for a particular or related script/function, should the occasion ever presents itself again. Don't get me wrong, I love helping out, and will even help for an hour if need be, to find a solution, and that's what it's all about, finding a solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
$data = file_get_contents('yourfile.txt');
echo '<textarea>', htmlspecialchars($data), '</textarea>';
```

The [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) loads the data, and then you just need to echo it.  Using [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) takes care of escaping any of the data, as needed in the context of HTML.

Comment: how can I write it in a certain textbox in my html form?

Comment: @hooman, `echo` it into the textarea you want it in.  If you want it in a normal input box, just echo it in as the value of the `value` attribute.  `echo '<input type="text" value="', htmlspecialchars($data), '" />';`

Comment: is it possible to write data in the html file that I previously prepared it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$textAreaContent = "";

$fp = fopen("read_file.txt", "r");

// If file exist and opened 
if($fp)
{
    while (($buffer = fgets($fp, 1024)) !== false)
        $testAreaContent .= $buffer;
}
```